# iframe runat="server" inner HTML being HTML encoded automatically

Tags: asp.net, iframe, .net-4.0, webforms, csquery

My master page has the `<!DOCTYPE>` and `<head>` section as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>CMIS</title>
    <link href="~/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="head" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
```

In a MyControl.ascx (FieldTemplateUserControl) I have:

```
<iframe id="Iframe1" runat="server" src="<%# GetNavigateUrl() %>" width="600" height="400">
    <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink2" runat="server" NavigateUrl="<%# GetNavigateUrl() %>" Target="_blank" Text="View" />
</iframe>
```

The HTML output of above on a rendered page is as follows:

```
<iframe id="ContentPlaceHolder1_FormView1_ctl04_ctl05___HelpHtml_Iframe1" width="600" height="400" src="/CMIS/Special/OutputHtml.aspx?Table=UserChecklist&Id=67">
    &lt;a id=&quot;ContentPlaceHolder1_FormView1_ctl04_ctl05___HelpHtml_HyperLink2&quot; href=&quot;/CMIS/Special/OutputHtml.aspx?Table=UserChecklist&amp;amp;Id=67&quot; target=&quot;_blank&quot;&gt;View&lt;/a&gt;
</iframe>
```

Surely the contents of the `<iframe>` shouldn't be HTML encoded? Is this an ASP.net bug?

How can I stop this from happening?

**EDIT: Sorry this is something to do with CsQuery (a DLL which is rendering the HTML)**

Comment: I'm not clear on what you're trying to do.  You want to show an IFRAME that loads the page at the URL returned by `GetNavigationURL`.  But you also want to have a hyperlink inside the IFRAME?  (Which I'm not sure you can do, anyway.)  Why?

Comment: post yout GetNavigateUrl()

Comment: @AnnL. For browsers which do not support iframes?

Comment: @BhavinChauhan I'm on my iPad ATM so can't easily post it, but it doesn't,t do anything special. It just builds and returns a string.

Comment: @Chris Cannon I just want to see your code b'cz have you used client id or not if you remove just runat server tag than "ContentPlaceHolder1_FormView1_ctl04_ctl05___HelpHtml_Iframe1" will become as Iframe1 whenever you free just post your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue being caused by DLL which is rendering the markup instead of normal ASP.NET rendering.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can put code *inside* an IFRAME tag.  An IFRAME can't have internal markup.  You can only load an IFRAME by setting its `src` attribute.

Comment: I thought you could put HTML inside an iframe for browsers which do not support iframes?